# How to find out local coordinates relative to the parent without adding an object to it? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, position, instantiation

I'm adding an object to the parent:

```
Transform target = Instantiate(_leftTargetPrefab, leftTargetPosition, Quaternion.identity);
target.SetParent(_ballsParent, false);
```

I'm trying to get the coordinates inside the parent, but they don't match:

```
Vector3 testPos = _ballsParent.InverseTransformPoint(leftTargetPosition);
```

Is it possible to find out the coordinates inside the parent without adding an object?

Comment: `I'm trying to get the coordinates inside the parent,  but they don't match:`  If you are comparing to the inspector position values, make sure the object in question is not parented, otherwise you are viewing the local position.  InverseTransformPoint should be the correct answer.  Also make sure you are using a world position in the function.

Answer (score 1):

To get the coordinates relative to the parent, you can subtract the coordinates by the parent's world position.

```
Vector3 relativeCoordinates = coordinates - transform.parent.position;
```

To get the position of a child relative to the parent you can use `transform.localPosition` instead of `transform.position`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i get you right.But if you are looking for a position of a child object try this:

```
var localPosition = _ballsParent.transform.Find("ChildName").transform.localPosition;
```

//Btw, the answer from "The Ash Bot" would be the better practice than find gameobject by the name :P